# Doctrine same table relation problem?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine

i am beginner to doctrine orm.

what is `hasmany` and `hasone` where exactly use this one .

tell me brief explanation.

And how to use same table relationship in Doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain it with an ewample :

"A house with many rooms"

If you have to create a database, you will have a table "house" and a table "room", and you have to define the relationships between the both.

A house can have many rooms : so your table have a relation One-to-Many (hasmany) with the table "room" => a record of "house" can be linked with several records of "room".

A room belong to one unique house : you have to use hasone => a record of "room" can be linked with one record of "house".

Comment: thanku.and i have emp table this emp table have empno and mgr relation who is the managar for that employee ?

Comment: I don't sure I have understand your question, have you some code you can post here ?